# How to return a specific string instead of (no changes, no records) in Cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

my query below returns "Success" string if node n successfully matched.
In case it was not matched, the output is "(no changes, no records)" while I expect the query to return "Failure" string.
I guess this is to do with node n not existing and therefore
'with value.rslt' is also not existing which returns nothing.
How can I get "Failure" return in case node n not matched?
Thank you

```
match(n:device) where n.nid = 'non-existing'
CALL apoc.do.case(
[
 n is not null, "return 'Success' as rslt"
], 
"return 'Failure' as rslt",
{n:n}
) yield value
with  value.rslt  as rslt 
return rslt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do `OPTIONAL MATCH`, it returns `NULL` when there are no nodes matching the condition.

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (n:device) 
WHERE n.nid = 'non-existing'
RETURN DISTINCT CASE n WHEN NULL THEN 'Failure' ELSE 'Success' END
```

Comment: Hi @NataliaZ if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by up-voting 
clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. Thanks!